What is the distribution of a linear combination of $Z$ and $Z^2$?
Question:
Let $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. What is the distribution of
$$Y = \alpha Z^2 +\beta Z$$
What I know:
It is well known that $Z^2\sim \chi^2(1)$. If we instead had independent RVs $Z$ and $W^2$ where $W\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ independent of $Z$, then the problem is easy since by independence, the CFs factor:
$$\phi_Y(s) = \mathbb{E}(e^{is Y})=\mathbb{E}(e^{is \alpha W^2}) \mathbb{E}(e^{is \beta Z})$$
$$=\phi_{W^2}(s\alpha) \phi_Z(s\beta)$$
and these are known CFs, so we get
$$\phi_Y(s) = (1-2is\alpha)^{-1/2} \cdot e^{-(s\beta)^2/2}.$$
For most purposes, knowing the CF is good enough: we can attempt to find an analytic or numeric inversion, or compute derivatives to obtain moments, or whatever else we would like.
Without the crutch of independence, I am not sure how to make any progress on this question. If you are interested in context, this distribution arises when applying the Milstein method to numerically solve a SDE $dX=\mu(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t$. Conditional on the current step $X_i=x_i$, the next step of the approximate solution is distributed like
$$X_{i+1}\stackrel{(d)}{=}x_i + \mu(x_i) h + \sigma(x_i) \sqrt{h} Z_{i+1} +0.5\sigma(x_i)\sigma'(x_i)(h Z_{i+1}^2-h)$$
where $Z_{i+1}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, which is essentially of the form
$$aZ^2 +b Z+c$$
absorbing all of the conditional terms into new coefficients.

Completing the square yields $$Y = \alpha Z^2 + \beta Z = \alpha\left(Z + \frac{\beta}{2\alpha}\right)^2 - \frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}. \tag{1}$$
Thus $Y$ is a location-scale transformed noncentral chi-square random variable with $1$ degree of freedom and noncentrality parameter $\lambda = (\frac{\beta}{2\alpha})^2$; specifically, $$\frac{Y + \frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}{\alpha}$$ is noncentral chi-squared.

+1 Ah, of course!--I am always embarrassed whenever I forgot about completing the square... Thank you.
